# Cant set CSS Rules for variable data from Javascript

Tags: javascript, html, css

I am unable to style a DIV with CSS that is passed from JavaScript..

In all of the variables that are passed from JAVASCRIPT to HTML in my code i am unable to style them with Width Or Height Or Colour etc...

For Instance below i am trying to set the size of an image to be 10px X 10px but only the full original size image displays..

**MY HTML:**

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>

<head>
<script src="/testsite/OneSecondPlaylist.js"></script>

<style type="text/css">
#list0picture {
width: 10px;
height: 10px;
}
</style>
```

```
<body onload="getPlaylist()">
<h1>Now Playing</h1>
<div id="list0artist"></div>
<div id="list0title"></div>
<div id="list0label"></div>
<div id="list0albumyear"></div>
<div id="list0picture"></div>

</body>

</html>
```

**MY JAVASCRIPT:**

```
function getPlaylist()
{
var xmlhttp,
timer;

if (window.XMLHttpRequest)
{
    xmlhttp = new XMLHttpRequest();
} 
else
{
    xmlhttp = new ActiveXObject("Microsoft.XMLHTTP");
}

xmlhttp.onreadystatechange = function ()
{
if (xmlhttp.readyState == 4 && xmlhttp.status == 200) 
{

var list = eval ('('+xmlhttp.responseText+')');
{

document.getElementById("list0artist").innerHTML=list[0].artist;
document.getElementById("list0title").innerHTML=list[0].title;
document.getElementById("list0label").innerHTML=list[0].label;
document.getElementById("list0albumyear").innerHTML=list[0].albumyear;
document.getElementById("list0picture").innerHTML='<img src="/testsite/covers/' + list[0].picture + '"/>';

}


}
};

xmlhttp.onerror = function() 
{
    clearTimeout(timer);
};

xmlhttp.open("GET", "playlist.php?t=" + Math.random(), true);
xmlhttp.send();


timer = setTimeout(getPlaylist, 1000);
```

}

With reference to The Image that is being displayed:
I know that i **Could** add attributes within JavaScript to set the size of the image when it is passed to HTML but i am having some issues with the image not locking in exactly to the DIV i create for it (example below)

```
document.getElementById("list0.picture").innerHTML='<img src="/testsite/covers/' +     list[0].picture + '" width="160px" height="auto"/>';
```

Comment: I'm sorry but your description of the problem is very chaotic. You should try to simplify your problem, get rid of all the things that doesn't affect the issue and post some sample code. How about you show us your CSS?

Comment: Are you assigning the style directly to the image or to the wrapper div? Unless you set the `overflow` on the container or the `max-(height|width)` on the image, you won't see a change.

Comment: @Mathletics Hi... i have tried both but the problem still persists.. I am unable to scale the image within CSS, only JavaScript... Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

In CSS, the selector `#list0.artist` looks like an element with ID `list0` and class `artist`. Don't use periods in your IDs for precisely this reason. If you must keep it, simply escape the dot, `#list0\.artist` in your selector.

Comment: Using dot in an ID is valid though, you just need to escape that dot in your stylesheet. But ya you are right I would avoid using dot in an ID for unnecessary confusion.

Comment: @Xavier_Ex I never said it was invalid, just that it causes headaches.

Comment: @Mathletics i have removed the "." from my code and cleaned up the question.. hope this explains things better. (the problem persists even after removing the ".")

Answer (score 0):

Well since you haven't provided any sample code, I can only assume that your CSS looks something like this:

```
#list0.artist {
    color: red;
}
```

And the color is not changed on the container `<div id="list0.artist"></div>`.

If this is the case then the problem is trivial, `#list0.artist` does not target an element having `id="list0.artist"` at all, it instead targets an element with `id="list0"` and at the same time `class="artist"`, since the dot in CSS indicates this is a class name, and by concatenating the ID and the class name together you are selecting an element with all those characteristics.

Instead escape the dot in your CSS like this: `#list0\.artist {}` and you should be fine.

Comment: i have removed the "." from my code and cleaned up the question.. hope this explains things better. (the problem persists even after removing the ".")